# Как в java прослушивать endpoint в realtime?

Tags: java, сеть

Есть сторонний endpoint, который иногда шлёт информацию. Через cURL всё видно, когда появляется инфа - тут же выводит. Но когда я в java пытаюсь тоже самое через HttpRequest, он собирает всё в один HttpResponse и при разрыве соеденения с сервером разом всё выводит. Из HttpRequest никакие I/O Stream не извлекаются. Есть способ сделать работу как в cURL'е?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, спустя час я разобрался.
Вот примерное решение:

```
        URLConnection connection = URI.create("endpoint's url").toURL().openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "key");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine())
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
```